# Need help finding the second Wednesday of a year

Tags: c#, datetime

I need help finding the second Wednesday of the year. Here is what I have done, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
DateTime baseDay = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 1, 5);
int secondWed = 5 + ((12 - (int)baseDay.DayOfWeek) % 7);
DateTime fullDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 1, secondWed);
```

Comment: sorry, its not working, because it returns the wrong date

Comment: duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421972/how-to-find-the-3rd-friday-in-a-month-with-c you have to search first!!

Comment: @mekici that thread is what i used as the basis for my code

Comment: @bugz: Your code doesn't resemble either the accepted answer nor the most upvoted answer. Try one of those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the very good answer by Mark Ransom to [How to find the 3rd Friday in a month with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421972/how-to-find-the-3rd-friday-in-a-month-with-c/5422046#5422046). There is no looping here.

```
var year = 2011;
var firstDayOfMonth = new DateTime(year, 1, 1);
var daysUntilNextWednesday = DayOfWeek.Wednesday - firstDayOfMonth.DayOfWeek;
if (daysUntilNextWednesday < 0)
  daysUntilNextWednesday += 7;
var firstWednesdayOfMonth = firstDayOfMonth.AddDays(daysUntilNextWednesday);
var secondWednesdayOfMonth = firstWednesdayOfMonth.AddDays(7);
```

You can merge the last two lines into one for slightly better performance.

Comment: this is great too! especially without the loop

Answer (score 12):

Try this method instead:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 1, 8); //get second week of the year
while(dt.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Wednesday) //loop until we find the next Wednesday
    dt = dt.AddDays(1);
```

Answer (score 2):

May be this helps

```
    DateTime startDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 1, 1);
    int c = (int)startDate.DayOfWeek;
    int n = (int)DayOfWeek.Wednesday;
    int weekcount=2;
    int diff = (7 - c + n);
    int days= (diff > 7) ? diff % 7 : diff;
    startDate.AddDays((weekcount-1)*7+ days );
```

Comment: couple of bugs in the above. what is d? the result of .AddDays is thrown away. even if I change 'd' to 'n' I don't get the right answer

Answer (score 1):

Something this simple would also work...

```
int weekNumber = 2;
DateTime seekingDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 1, 1);
while (seekingDate.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Wednesday)
    seekingDate = seekingDate.AddDays(1);

seekingDate.AddDays(7 * (weekNumber - 1));
```

Of course, I would use variable for the weekday and the week number.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this would also work:

```
var date = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year,1,1);
if(date.DayOfWeek > DayOfWeek.Tuesday)
    date = date.AddDays(9 - (int)date.DayOfWeek);
else if(date.DayOfWeek < DayOfWeek.Tuesday)
    date = date.AddDays(2 - (int)date.DayOfWeek);
date = date.AddDays(7);
```