# Getting specific days in a month

Tags: asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find the 3rd Friday in a month with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421972/how-to-find-the-3rd-friday-in-a-month-with-c)

There's a condition that a specific event will occur only on **first** and **third** **Wednesday** of every month. I am trying to achieve this like below,

```
DateTime nextMeeting = DateTime.Today.AddDays(14);
int daysUntilWed = ((int)DayOfWeek.Wednesday - (int)nextMeeting.DayOfWeek + 7) % 7;
DateTime nextWednesday = nextMeeting.AddDays(daysUntilWed);
```

But I am not getting the desired result. I am sure, I am missing out on a logic or is there any method in ASP.NET through which I can do that?
More Detail:  I am trying to display the next Wednesday (whichever is first) by clicking on a button which will set the label.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var FirstDay = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1);

//first wednesday
while (FirstDat.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Wednesday)
       FirstDay = FirstDate.AddDays(1);

//3rd wednesday
var ThirdWed = FirstDay.AddDays(14);
```