# Get first Saturday of month and last Friday of last week of month

Tags: datetime, reporting-services, report-designer

This need is a little strange, and I can do it in C#, but can't seem to get the expression syntax right for Report Designer.

I want to set default Start and End parameters for a report.  To do this, I need "date only" values for the first Saturday of a month, and the Friday date of the last week of that month.  This means the latter value can actually be in the next month.  So for 2012, my values would look like this:

StartDate:  10/06/2012
EndDate: 11/02/2012

StartDate: 11/03/2012
EndDate: 11/30/2012

StartDate: 12/01/2012
EndDate: 01/04/2013

I've been working with conditional statements using Month(), Weekday(), WeekdayName, etc. but not having good luck.  Has anyone done something like this?

Comment: I don't know Visual Studio Report Designer, but it sounds like the End parameter can also be defined as: "the _last_ Saturday of the month **plus** six days". That's also: "the last Friday on or before the 6th day of the _next_ month". Don't know if that helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't need any hefty conditional statements. If you're doing it to simulate loops and other imperative programming features, it may be easier to create a function in [Custom Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156028.aspx) to do it.

An alterantive is to look for an algorithm for the particular calculations you're doing. For example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5422046/419956) can be a great basis for getting your needed dates, be it with a little adjustment. Here's how it would work for *"The first Saturday of this month"*:

1. Day of the week for the day 1 of this month:

   ```vb
   =Weekday(DateAdd("d", 1 - Now().Day, Now()), FirstDayOfWeek.Sunday)
   ```
2. How many days should we add to that first day of the month:

   ```vb
   =7 - Weekday(DateAdd("d", 1 - Now().Day, Now()), FirstDayOfWeek.Sunday)
   ```
3. So the date for the first Saturday of the month is:

   ```vb
   =DateAdd("d", 
        7 - Weekday(DateAdd("d", 1 - Now().Day, Now()), FirstDayOfWeek.Sunday),
        DateAdd("d", 1 - Now().Day, Now())
       )
   ```

There are probably even smarter ways to do this, though VBScript expressions *are* a wee bit limited. The example above can be tweaked to get the "Friday of the last week of the month" as well.

***Bottom line***: the (indirect, but generic) answer to your question is to think about the algorithm to get to your wanted date (as declarative as possible, because you can't do loops and stuff in Expressions easily).

Comment: Jeroen, thank you for walking through that methodically. It helped to see how you reasoned your way through it.  I can use that same approach to get the end date as well.

Comment: I am not much of a coder other than SQL. I was unaware of the FirstDayOfWeek command. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I got for the first part. There is probably a much better way to accomplish this. What I did was get the current month and subract one from it. Then I concatenated the date and the current year to the month. Then I did a check on the name of the day to see if it was Saturday. If it was, then I used that date. Otherwise I did the next day with the same check, and so on. If you want to use this, you will need to add additional logic to it if you are in January. You would also substitute NOW() with the parameter you are using.

```
=IIF( WeekdayName(DatePart("w", (CDate((Month(NOW()) - 1) & "/1/" & YEAR(NOW()))))) = "Saturday", (CDate((Month(NOW()) - 1) & "/1/" & YEAR(NOW()))), 
(IIF( WeekdayName(DatePart("w", (CDate((Month(NOW()) - 1) & "/2/" & YEAR(NOW()))))) = "Saturday", (CDate((Month(NOW()) - 1) & "/2/" & YEAR(NOW()))), 
    (IIF( WeekdayName(DatePart("w", (CDate((Month(NOW()) - 1) & "/3/" & YEAR(NOW()))))) = "Saturday", (CDate((Month(NOW()) - 1) & "/3/" & YEAR(NOW()))),
        (IIF( WeekdayName(DatePart("w", (CDate((Month(NOW()) - 1) & "/4/" & YEAR(NOW()))))) = "Saturday", (CDate((Month(NOW()) - 1) & "/4/" & YEAR(NOW()))),
            (IIF( WeekdayName(DatePart("w", (CDate((Month(NOW()) - 1) & "/5/" & YEAR(NOW()))))) = "Saturday", (CDate((Month(NOW()) - 1) & "/5/" & YEAR(NOW()))),
                (IIF( WeekdayName(DatePart("w", (CDate((Month(NOW()) - 1) & "/6/" & YEAR(NOW()))))) = "Saturday", (CDate((Month(NOW()) - 1) & "/6/" & YEAR(NOW()))),
                    (IIF( WeekdayName(DatePart("w", (CDate((Month(NOW()) - 1) & "/7/" & YEAR(NOW()))))) = "Saturday", (CDate((Month(NOW()) - 1) & "/7/" & YEAR(NOW()))),
"1/1/2010")))))))))))))
```

On another note, there would be a very easy way to get this if you have a calendar table in SQL Server (especially for when you need the Friday). You could do a simple select statement such as the following:

```
SELECT
    MIN(date)
FROM
    calendar c
WHERE
    MONTH(DATEADD("m", -1, GETDATE())) = MONTH(date)
    AND YEAR(DATEADD("m", -1, GETDATE())) = YEAR(date)
    AND datename(dw, date) = 'Saturday'
```

Comment: Neil, thanks for the helpful reply.  I've done nested IIFs but never that many!!  ;-)

Comment: Thanks to BOTH of you (Neil and Jeroen).  I have managed to massage your examples to get the First Saturday and Friday of the last week of the preceding month. (We always bill one month in arears.)  I would like to select BOTH answers as the accepted answer because I really had two problems and used your sample code to solve each.

Answer (score -1):

Get the Last Friday of the last month.....

=DateAdd(DateInterval.Day,- Weekday(DateAdd("d", 1 - Now().Day, Now()), FirstDayOfWeek.Saturday), DateSerial(Year(Date.Now), Month(Date.Now), 1))