# Add monthly clustered task in PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduled-tasks, failovercluster

I have a big problem with creating: ***clustered monthly task*** on windows server via PowerShell.

All info which I found about my problem was monthly, but locally. I need tasks on cluster.

Anyone can help me with some code to create that task ?

Best regards.
Bartolini

Comment: Have you checked [Register-ClusteredScheduledTask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/register-clusteredscheduledtask?view=win10-ps)?

Comment: Yes, there is no monthly :(

Comment: Use, say, weekly schedule instead. As first step, [calculate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5422046/503046) if it's being invoked on desired day and continue if so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to create daily tasks. On startup parameters I will sent a day number and month. Then check on which date number and month I want to run that task, if it's match then execute.